# Dimension dependence of Curie Weiß Hamiltonian

Tags: solid-state-physics, magnetic-moment

The Hamiltonian for the Ising model on a lattice $\Lambda$ is:
\begin{align}
  H(S) &= - J \sum\limits_{i \sim j} S_i S_j
          - B \sum\limits_i S_i \\
        &=
          - J \sum\limits_i\sum\limits_{j: i\sim j} S_i S_j
          - B \sum\limits_i S_i
\end{align}
Where $J \in \mathbb{R}$ is the coupling constant
  and $B \in \mathbb{R}$ is the magnetic field (with constants).
If $n_i = |\{j \in \Lambda: i \sim j\}|$  is the number of corners
  neighbouring $i$, then for a rectangular grid in $d$ dimensions we have:
$n_i = 2d$.
If we rewrite the coupling term for a given $i$, we get:
\begin{align}
  -J \sum\limits_{j:i \sim j} S_i S_j
    = - 2 d J S_i \frac{1}{2 d} \sum\limits_{j:i \sim j} S_j
\end{align}
We can interpret the term:
\begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{2 d} \sum\limits_{j:i \sim j} S_j
\end{equation}
as average magnetisation around $i$.
In the Curie-Weiß-Ising Modells we make the assumption of replacing this $i$ dependent magnetisation environment by the average magnetisation.
\begin{equation}
  \label{E:mean_field_approximation}
  \frac{1}{2 d} \sum\limits_{j:i \sim j} S_j
    \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{j \neq i} S_j
\end{equation}
If we include the $2d$ term into $J$ we end up with a new coupling constant.

So now my question:

Do you know of experimental papers where they measured coupling constants for different dimensions? e.g. 2D and 3D lattices.